# How to launch a IE TAB with medium integrity?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, com, automation

Problem -

For standard user on win7, given a running instance of IE on desktop, how do I launch a new TAB inside this IE window with integrity level 'medium'.

So far,
I enumerate all shell windows then cast them to IWebBrowser2 and call Navigate2(navOpenInNewTab) on any of these to get new tab with integrity level 'low' I want this to be of 'medium'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it directly .. we can create a new tab in existing instance of IE using Navigate2() API but the tab which gets launched has low integrity .. now this tab automatically gets swapped with tab of medium integrity if the URL is trusted URL .. this swapping happens behind the scene and unaware users do not know this .. trapping NewProcess event using EventSink can help handling this tab swapping